# Rust + mio tcp client: explicit lifetime required in the type of connection

Tags: rust, mio

I want to implement tcp client using mio. This is my code:

```
pub struct Client<'a> {
    pub connected: bool,
    connection: Option<&'a TcpStream>,
    auth_handler: auth::AuthHandler<'a>,
}

impl Client<'_> {
    pub fn connect(&mut self, host: &str, port: i16) {
        let addr_list = format!("{}:{}", host, port)
            .to_socket_addrs()
            .unwrap();

        let addr = addr_list.last().unwrap();

        match TcpStream::connect(addr) {
            Ok(stream) => {
                self.connected = true;
                self.connection = Some(&stream);
                self.auth_handler.init(self.connection.unwrap());
                self.auth_handler.authenticate("login".to_string(), "password".to_string());
                println!("Connected to {}:{}", host, port);
            }
            Err(..) => {
                println!("Cannot connect !");
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn listen(&mut self) {
        let mut connection = self.connection.as_mut().unwrap();
        let mut poll = Poll::new().unwrap();
        let mut events = Events::with_capacity(256);

        poll.registry().register(
            connection,
            CLIENT,
            Interest::READABLE | Interest::WRITABLE
        );

        loop {
            poll.poll(&mut events, None).unwrap();

            for event in events.iter() {
                match event.token() {
                    CLIENT => {
                        if event.is_writable() {
                            // ...
                        }

                        if event.is_readable() {
                            println!("Data")
                        }
                    },
                    _ => (),
                }
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn new<'a>() -> Client<'a> {
        Client {
            connected: false,
            connection: None,
            auth_handler: auth::AuthHandler {
                connection: None::<&'a TcpStream>,
            },
        }
    }
}
```

and code of my auth handler:

```
pub struct AuthHandler<'a> {
    pub connection: Option<&'a TcpStream>,
}

impl AuthHandler {
    pub fn authenticate(&self, login: String, password: String) {
        // ...
    }

    pub fn new<'a>() -> AuthHandler<'a> {
        AuthHandler {
            connection: None::<&'a TcpStream>,
        }
    }

    pub fn init(&mut self, connection: &TcpStream) {
        self.connection = Some(&connection);  // error here see ERRORS below
    }
}
```

on compile I got an error "error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of connection":

```
self.connection = Some(&connection);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required
```

how to fix it ? From my side I am not sure if `static` lifetime is OK since I want to destroy connection once authenticated and logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime of `connection` is really `'a`, but from the code you've posted nobody owns the `TcpStream`. You could fix the specific error you're having by using the `AuthHandler`s lifetime:

```rust
impl<'a> AuthHandler<'a> {
    pub fn authenticate(&self, login: String, password: String) {
        // ...
    }

    pub fn new() -> AuthHandler {
        AuthHandler {
            connection: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn init(&mut self, connection: &'a TcpStream) {
        self.connection = Some(connection);
    }
}
```

But I would expect that you would then get other errors, because in effect `Client` is a self-referential struct.

So one way to share the connection between these objects would be to put it inside a `Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>` and share that between your two objects:

```rust
pub struct Client<'a> {
    pub connected: bool,
    connection: Option<Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>>,
    auth_handler: auth::AuthHandler<'a>,
}

pub struct AuthHandler {
    pub connection: Option<Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>>,
}
```

then the `TcpStream` will stay alive as long as you need it. Of course, you would need to `.lock()` it whenever you use it.

Another option would be to only pass the `TcpStream` to `AuthHandler` when it uses it:

```rust
pub struct AuthHandler;

impl AuthHandler {
    pub fn authenticate(&self, login: String, password: String, stream: &TcpStream) {
        // ...
    }
}
```